# Cython: Memory view of freed memory

Tags: python, memory, cython, free, memoryview

In Cython code, I can allocate some memory and wrap it in a memory view, e.g. like this:

```
cdef double* ptr
cdef double[::1] view
ptr = <double*> PyMem_Malloc(N*sizeof('double'))
view = <double[:N]> ptr
```

If I now free the memory using `PyMem_Free(ptr)`, trying to access elements like `ptr[i]` throws an error, as it should. However, I can safely try to access `view[i]` (it does not return the original data though).

My question is this: Is it always safe to just deallocate the pointer? Is the memory view object somehow informed of the memory being freed, or should I manually remove the view somehow? Also, is the memory guaranteed to be freed, even though it is referred to by memory views?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It requires a bit of digging into the C code to show this, but:

The line `view = <double[:N]> ptr` actually generates a `__pyx_array_obj`. This is the same type detailed in [the documentation as a "Cython array" and cimportable as `cython.view.array`](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/memoryviews.html#cython-arrays). The Cython array does have an optional member called `callback_free_data` that can act as a destructor.

The line translates as:

```
struct __pyx_array_obj *__pyx_t_1 = NULL;
# ...
__pyx_t_1 = __pyx_array_new(__pyx_t_2, sizeof(double), PyBytes_AS_STRING(__pyx_t_3), (char *) "c", (char *) __pyx_v_ptr);
```

(`__pyx_t_2` and `__pyx_t_3` are just temporaries storing the size and format respectively). If we look inside `__pyx_array_new` we see firstly that the array's `data` member is assigned directly to the value passed as `__pyx_v_ptr`

```
__pyx_v_result->data = __pyx_v_buf;
```

(i.e. a copy is *not* made) and secondly that `callback_free_data` is not set. *Side note:* The C code for `cython.view.array` is actually generated from [Cython code](https://github.com/cython/cython/blob/8168063752f0050ee53fda80c4d679c0d0f5389b/Cython/Utility/MemoryView.pyx) so if you want to investigate further it's probably easier to read that than the generated C.

---

Essentially, the memoryview holds a `cython.view.array` which has a pointer to the original data, but no `callback_free_data` set. When the memoryview dies the destructor for the `cython.view.array` is called. This cleans up a few internals, but does nothing to free the data it points to (since it has no indication of how to do so).

It is therefore *not safe* to access the memoryview after you have called `PyMem_Free`. That fact you seem to get away with it is luck. It is safe for the memoryview to keep existing though, providing you don't access it. A function like:

```
def good():
    cdef double* ptr
    cdef double[::1] view
    ptr = <double*> PyMem_Malloc(N*sizeof('double'))
    try:
        view = <double[:N]> ptr
        # some other stuff
    finally:
        PyMem_Free(ptr)
    # some other stuff not involving ptr or view
```

would be fine. A function like:

```
def bad():
    cdef double* ptr
    cdef double[::1] view
    ptr = <double*> PyMem_Malloc(N*sizeof('double'))
    try:
        view = <double[:N]> ptr
        # some other stuff
    finally:
        PyMem_Free(ptr)
    view[0] = 0
    return view
```

would be a bad idea since it's passing back a memoryview that doesn't point to anything, and accessing `view` after the data it views has been freed.

You should definitely make sure to call `PyMem_Free` at some point, otherwise you have a memory leak. One way of doing it if `view` gets passed around and so the lifetime is hard to track would be to manually create a `cython.view.array` with `callback_free_data` set:

```
cdef view.array my_array = view.array((N,), allocate_buffer=False)
my_array.data = <char *> ptr
my_array.callback_free_data = PyMem_Free
view = my_array
```

If the lifetime of `view` is obvious then you can just call `PyMem_Free` on `ptr` as you've been doing.